# uploading screenshots itunes connect resolution

Tags: screenshot, app-store-connect

My app adjust to screen so it looks the same on every device. Can i resize my screenshots for every type or do I have to create new ones? The reason I am asking is I wonder if apple would reject my app if all the screenshots would be the same but their resolution is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upload the same image, but with different resolutions, according to the device.

Open the image in a editor, like preview in mac, and redimention your image to the pixels you want:

[image]

Save with diferent names and upload to each device.